# Stop html input responding to href link

Tags: html, css, input, href

I have a link that is embedded in a border that acts as a button, however I only want a click to be registered in the outer part of the button, not when the user clicks inside the input (search) box.

```
<a href='search'>
  <div class='button' id='search_head' style='margin-right: 1em;'>
    <input class='search' placeholder="&nbsp;e.g. blue jeans" type='text'/>
    <img src='img/mag_glass_nav.png' height='20' weight='20' />
    &nbsp; Search
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Then you should NOT put an `input` inside a link...

Comment: Show your css style definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't get it!, but i think you shouldn't do that! - **DON'T WRAP INPUT ELEMENT WITHIN ANCHOR TAG!!**
Just wrap your input element and search link within a div with relative position to be able to position the search link. [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wikiziner/2Jc3t/)

```
<div class="search-wrapper">
    <input class='search' placeholder="e.g. blue jeans" type='text' /> 
    <a href="search">
         <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wpzoom-developer-icon-set/500/67-24.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML5 spec for [the `<a>` element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) says that "there must be no interactive content descendant"

Comment: No, you didn't do anything wrong :) I was just pointing out the reason why your answer is correct - "Interactive content" just means elements you can interact with (i.e. the input)

Answer (score 0):

Change simply your markup to something like this :

```
<input class='search' placeholder="&nbsp;e.g. blue jeans" type='text'/>
 <a href='search'>
 <div class='button' id='search_head' style='margin-right: 1em;'><img src='img/mag_glass_nav.png' height='20' weight='20'>&nbsp; Search
 </div>
</a>
```